# How can I paint over an existing paint design without making it permanent?

Tags: drywall, paint, wallpaper

We have a baby on the way. We are currently designing the nursery. The room currently has a diamond-shaped pattern that we'd like to keep, since it is unique and cool looking, plus it came that way when we purchased the house. The problem is, we are doing a 'Winnie the Pooh' theme nursery. We wanted to do a green grass with blue sky landscape on that wall. However, as stated, we don't want to paint over it. We are afraid of using plain white wallpaper and painting on it, because a lot of times when removing wall paper, it will tear or damage the wall/paint it was glued to. I've found 'temporary' or 'removable' wallpaper, but its way too pricey for our budget. We considered white wall panels or even dry wall, but didn't seem like a good idea.

Is there anything TEMPORARY we can install over the existing wall/paint, that can be removed down the road without damaging or ruining the existing wall paint/design? Some type of material we can paint and that would be sturdy (as it will be the main focal wall behind the crib). Any ideas of materials we can use to cover the existing wall so we can paint over it, or some other temporary solution that wont ruin the original wall would be appreciated. I've scoured over the internet with no answers as of yet, besides the VERY expensive removable wallpaper.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas

- hang up fabric?
- go to a large format printer (sign shop) and print banners and hang those?
- get $10 shower panelling from Home Depot and tack those up on the wall (and paint on those)
- don't bother with a 'theme' for the baby's room. I know a lot of people like to do it, but it's a lot of work, the kid doesn't really care, and they grow out of it really fast. That and for a lot of people, the baby ends up sleeping in the parents room anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Fatheads.  I think fatheads or a copy cat competitor make baby themed stickers.  We have hot air balloons and a paris scene stickers in our baby room.  If you are looking for total wall cover like wallpaper I would buy the cheapest self stick stuff and paint over it - doing a very small test area to begin with. Or self stick baby wallpaper.  You have to worry about residue and the stick material ruining paint.  This depends on the wallpaper and how the room was painted.  If you will only be using the baby room for a short time I wouldn't cover the whole wall with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Paintable peelable mask. Used for movie set use and reuse.

Don't know if it's any cheaper than the removable wallpaper.

I have used their removable bathtub liner when doing bath remodel where the tub stayed, and I recommend that.. Just peeled off no residue.

[General Chemical paintable mask](http://www.strippablecoating.com/tvmoviestudios_masking.aspx)

Their specific product, [Studio Protect film](http://generalchemicalcorp.mybigcommerce.com/products/Studio_Protectfilm_2810.html) is water based

[image]

Comment: I have used these before for different things.  Reason why I didn't recommend is that although it doesn't have a residue I have noticed the paint dulling/fading a bit underneath.  Not sure if it was because of the brand or length of time on the wall.  If you have an intricate, well painted wall, I don't think I would chance it.